# Double integral Simpsons rule in python where the limits are functions

Tags: python, simpsons-rule

I have created a function where it can solve double integrals using the Simpsons rule but it only works when the limits of integration are constants

```
def double_integration(a,b,y1,y2,f,n):
    
    ### First, check that the number of strips is even.
    if n % 2 != 0:
        sys.exit("We require an even number of strips in Simpson's rule.")

    #Set up evaluation points in each direction
    xvals = np.linspace(a,b,n+1)
    yvals = np.linspace(y1,y2,n+1)

    hx = (b-a)/n #Mesh width in x direction
    hy = (y2-y1)/n #Mesh width in y direction

    #Set temporary weights in each coordinate direction
    weights = np.ones(n+1)
    weights[0] = 1/3
    weights[n] = 1/3
    
    for w in range (1,n):
        if w % 2 != 0:
            weights[w] = 4/3
        elif w % 2 == 0:
            weights[w] = 2/3

    #Scale with the mesh width in each direction to obtain actual weights
    x_weights = hx*weights
    y_weights = hy*weights

    integral = 0.0 #Initialise the approximation

    for i in range(n+1): #Loop over points in x-direction
        xi = xvals[i] 
        for j in range(n+1): #Loop over points in y-direction 
            yj = yvals[j]

            #Update the approximation
            integral += x_weights[i]*y_weights[j]*f(xi,yj)

    return integral

#First Test - Rectangular domain
f = lambda x,y: x**2*y
a = 1; b = 2
y1 = lambda x: np.ones(np.shape(x))
y2 = lambda x: 2*np.ones(np.shape(x))
n = 10
integral1 = double_integration(f,a,b,y1,y2,n)

#Second Test - Triangular domain
f = lambda x,y: np.ones(np.shape(x))
a = 0; b = 2
y1 = lambda x: -x
y2 = lambda x: x
n = 20
integral2 = double_integration(f,a,b,y1,y2,n)
```

but it doesn't pass these tests and will give the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'. But i'm unsure on how to fix it

Comment: What is the full error message? Which line of code causes the error? Please show an example that causes this error. Which variables are "the limits of integration"?

Answer (score 0):

You do one little mistake
y1 and y2 are not a number here and you deal like numbers.